# Verificações periodicas Django

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

Como eu poderia criar um loop, thread ou qualquer coisa que meu webapp verificasse periodiacamente a cada 5min o banco de dados e excluisse entradas que estiverem "vencidas".

Pesquisei mas não encontrei nada especifico. Até achei algo dizendo que deveria se criar um outro programa que acesse uma api do app para fazer essa comunicação. Não sei se essa é a opção mais eficiente ou "profissional".

Obrigado a todos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O que você quer fazer, poderia ser facilmente conseguido através do [Celery](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/index.html), mais especificamente das [Periodic Tasks](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html). Na documentação você vai encontrar exemplos com Django.

Comment: Nossa muito Bom. Obrigado parece que realmente isso resolve o problema.